# Sidekiq logs show JobWrapper instead of Job class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a Rails application that runs some background jobs via **ActiveJob** and **Sidekiq**. The sidekiq logs in both the terminal and the log file show the following:

```
2016-10-18T06:17:01.911Z 3252 TID-oukzs4q3k ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper JID-97318b38b1391672d21feb93 INFO: start
```

Is there some way to show the class names of the jobs here similar to how logs work for a regular Sidekiq Worker?

Update:

Here is how a Sidekiq worker logs:

```
2016-10-18T11:05:39.690Z 13678 TID-or4o9w2o4 ClientJob JID-b3c71c9c63fe0c6d29fd2f21 INFO: start
```

Update 2:

My sidekiq version is `3.4.2`

I'd like to replace `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper` with `Client Job`

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to do this by removing `Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Logging` from the middleware configuration and adding a modified class that displays the arguments in the logs. The arguments themself contain the job and action names as well.

For latest version, currently `4.2.3`, in `sidekiq.rb`

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/middleware/server/logging'

class ParamsLogging < Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Logging
  def log_context(worker, item)
    klass = item['wrapped'.freeze] || worker.class.to_s
    "#{klass} (#{item['args'].try(:join, ' ')}) JID-#{item['jid'.freeze]}"
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.remove Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Logging
    chain.add ParamsLogging
  end
end
```

For version `3.4.2`, or similar, override the `call` method instead:

```
class ParamsLogging < Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Logging
  def call(worker, item, queue)
    klass = item['wrapped'.freeze] || worker.class.to_s
    Sidekiq::Logging.with_context("#{klass} (#{item['args'].try(:join, ' ')}) JID-#{item['jid'.freeze]}") do
      begin
        start = Time.now
        logger.info { "start" }
        yield
        logger.info { "done: #{elapsed(start)} sec" }
      rescue Exception
        logger.info { "fail: #{elapsed(start)} sec" }
        raise
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll refrain from accepting this answer for now as I'd like to see a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running some ancient version.  Upgrade.

Sorry, looks like that's a Rails 5+ feature only. You'll need to upgrade Rails.  https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8d2b1406bc201d8705e931b6f043441930f2e8ac

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version and there result was still the same. The class name still evaluates to `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper`. In any case, is there any way of displaying the job name while keeping the old version (3.4.2)?